# In Component, what's the best pattern for creating configuration at system-start?

Tags: clojure, components, state

There's a pattern I haven't figured out for Component yet:

I have some "live" configuration that requires disk IO (a component) on `system-start`, and has a dependency on a map of static config (.edn), and after this "live" configuration is instantiated, it won't change or side-effect anything anymore.

For ex: I need to set this up once, and it depends on static config:

```
(buddy.core.backends/jws 
  {:secret (buddy.core.keys/public-key 
       path-to-public-key-from-static-config)})
```

I would then reuse that backend ad-infinitum, (ex: in `buddy.auth.middleware/wrap-authentication`), and it doesn't change, nor side-effect.

## Possible Solutions

1. I could make a component that stores this backend at `system-start`. But this gives up generality, because when I want to add similar "live config", it would have to be explicitly written into the component, and that gives up the spirit of generality that I think Component champions (eg `Duct` says components define side-effects, and create boundaries to access them)
2. I could pass a generic component a map of `keys` - `[fn & args]` and the fn+args get evaluated and stored in the component. But this feels like it offloads computation to my configuration .edn, and is an anti-pattern. For example:

   `(private-key priv-path-from-static 
         (slurp :password-path-from-static))`

   Should I encode the notion of `slurp`ing in my .edn config? I don't want to offload computation to a config file...
3. The backend and keys can be instantiated on a per-need basis *within* each component that requires them. IMO, that's too much of computing the exact same thing, when I'd rather it be stored in memory once.
4. I could have an `atom` component that holds a map of these "live" config objects, but then they get destructively added in, and my code has lost it's declarative nature.

## TL;DR

What's the best way to create configuration at `system-start`, possibly needing dependencies, and then becoming available to other components *as* a component, while not giving up the generality which components should have?

Comment: I don't follow why 1. would loose generality. This might be because you don't post any system / component example code -- could you elaborate? Components don't have to have side-effects and either way reading is a side-effect. Finally, component usually comes at the price of expecting "full buy-in", so you often end up with a tree of components. To address your TL;DR question: create a separate component that expects parameters (handed in by component as component maps), does its thing (reading, DB, whatever) on `component/start` and gives back a component for use with other components.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, I think the component itself should describe what type of configuration data it needs. (This could be done with a protocol extending the component in question.). When the config component is started, it should look at all other components, get the list of config requirements and resolve it somehow (from a file, a database, etc.).

I've not seen such a library, but [Aviso's config library](https://github.com/AvisoNovate/config) comes close, maybe you can adapt it to your needs.